# Find rank and nullity of this matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -9 & 6 \\ -2 & 6 & -4 \\ 1 & -3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

a) Find the basis for the nullspace of A and state nullity.
b) Find the basis for the column space of A. State the rank of A.

Solutions:

a) $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -9 & 6 \\ -2 & 6 & -4 \\ 1 & -3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 & 2 \\ -2 & 6 & -4 \\ 3 & -9 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

If there's one row and three variables, does this mean I have to set two free variables?

Let $x_3 = t, x_2 = s, x_1 = 3s - 2t$

$$x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3s - 2t \\ s \\ t \end{bmatrix} = s * \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + t * \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

a) nullity (number of vectors in the basis of the nullspace) is 2 and the basis is $(\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix})$

b) basis for column space: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the rank is = 1.

Is this right? Is there a more formal way to find b besides saying it's clear that since each column has a value in the same coordinate of each column, then the standard vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ must be the basis?

Comment: For (b): write down the definition of "column space". I do not think that is the basis vector.

Comment: But I'm trying to find the basis of the column space (subspace of $R^{number of rows} spanned by the column vectors of A @xbh

Comment: Then explicitly determine the column space, i.e. complete the calculation.

Comment: Rank is $1$ because there is a single independent vector and $\text{nullity} =\text{dimension}-\text{rank}=3-1=2$

Comment: Is _any_ of the three columns a multiple of $(1,0,0)^T$?

Comment: @amd yes? Isn't that right?

Comment: Ohhhh since the columns in matrix B (the rref) are all linearly independent, I have to find the corresponding columns in A right?

Comment: Correct! You can read a basis for the _row_ and _null_ spaces directly from the rref, but elementary row operations change the column space, so you have to go back to the original matrix.